# Find the points within radius using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In my table I have three columns ID , long and lat how  to find points within radius (ex., 20 km with center long and lat) without using PostGIS.

Comment: Well, it's not impossible, but it's so oppressively difficult that you really ought to just use PostGIS.  And be sure to name your "long" column "lon".

Comment: Furthermore, with PostGIS, you can answer the more useful question what the N nearest points are (independent of any arbitrary radius), and it has geographic indexes so that you can get these answers in a reasonable amount of time even for large tables.

Comment: This is also supported with a supplied module in vanilla Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/earthdistance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the haversine formula, using your current coordinates (target_latitude_deg/longitude) and the column name (latitude_deg, longitude_deg), both expressed in degrees

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE acos(
       sin(radians(target_latitude_deg)) 
         * sin(radians(latitude_deg)) 
       + cos(radians(target_latitude_deg)) 
         * cos(radians(latitude_deg)) 
         * cos( radians(target_longitude_deg)
           - radians(longitude_deg))
       ) * 6371 <= 20;
```

Comment: Thank you now  its working fine